# How to listen to a webrtc stream from mediamtx in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, webrtc, video-streaming

I am unable to find details on how to properly establish the connection between a flutter mobile app and the mediamtx server, judging from documentation I am supposed to use WHIP but no further details are given besides the general documentation page which is also not very clear.

I searched everywhere I could and just experimented but was unable to find any clear answer.
What endpoints should I communicate with and such or where can I find more info on that?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.